# Django-south: "! These migrations are in the database but not on disk:"

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, django-south, database-migration

I am trying to migrate a database, after modifying the schema in the `models.py` file of my app in Django. When I try to migrate using `./manage.py migrate <app-name>`, it gives the following message:

`! These migrations are in the database but not on disk:`

As I went through the `schemamigration_table` and the files, I noticed that for my last schema migration, the file (which added a table and a column in another table successfully) is not present for some reason. Is there any way I could perform my migration without resetting the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

If you are absolutely confident about the migration to have already applied to the database, You can safely use the [`--fake` option.](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html)

```
./manage.py migrate <app-name> --fake
```

This would forward the migrations to the most recent migration.

> --fake: Records the migration sequence as having been applied, but doesn’t actually run it. Useful for Converting An App.